# How can I enable automatic code suggestions in eclipse for c++?

Tags: c++, eclipse, ide, eclipse-cdt

I've decided to use eclipse as my primary IDE for c++ coding but I can't seem to figure out the automatic autocomplete. When I press `ctrl` + `space` it shows them just fine but not when I'm typing normally. I tried browsing through the settings but in content assist setting under `auto-activation` it only has checkboxes for `.`, `::`, and `->` triggers and not for letters, numbers and parentheses. I tried browsing around the web and all the solutions were for the java version of the eclipse IDE, not the c++ one.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible with the C++ editor. As you described, automatic trigger for content assist only works after typing `.`, `->` or `::` (if enabled) and there is no way to make it work for other combinations. See the dialog below:

[image]

As you mentioned, `Ctrl + Space` can always be used to manually launch the tool, but I understand it can become annoying.

So to answer your question: No, it is not possible (for C++).